# Spring H2 database lost data when re-running application every execute

Tags: java, spring-boot

**application.properties**

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:ecommerce
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username= xxx
spring.datasource.password= xxx
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

I am trying to connect the H2 database in Spring Boot application and the database data lost every execute so how to have the data be stored even re-executing the application it won't be deleted automatically?

I am figuring out the solution and problems but got stuck

Answer (score 1):

You are storing it in-memory `:mem:` try to store it [locally on disk](https://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#embedded_databases) `jdbc:h2:file:~/ecommerce` or use [server](https://www.h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#using_server) for it.

Comment: After I stored on local disk how to access the database?

Comment: what do you mean how? With jdbc or what?

Comment: I may want to check what data is stored in database with H2

Comment: You have the console enabled so you can access to the UI and display the data directly

Comment: add `AUTO_SERVER=TRUE` to the url...so smt like this `jdbc:h2:file:~/ecommerce;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE` then you should be able to access h2 from multiple processes